# how can i open a random text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to make a python program that randomly selects a text file to open and outputs the contents of the randomly selected text file

when i try running the code, i get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//fileserva/home$/K59046/Documents/project/project.py", line 8, in 
o = open(text, "r")
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

this is the code that i have written

```
import os
import random
os.chdir('N:\Documents\project\doodoo')
a = os.getcwd()
print("current dir is",a)
file = random.randint(1, 4)
text = (file,".txt")
o = open(text, "r")
print (o.read())
```

can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: (1) You should always use raw strings when constructing paths with backslashes: `os.chdir(r'N:\Documents\project\doodoo')`. (2) Use string formatting to create the filename: `text = f'{random.randint(1, 4)}.txt'`.

Comment: You should always use pathlib when you fiddle with paths 

Answer (score 2):

As your error message says, your `text` variable is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), not a string. You can use f-strings or string concatenation to solve this:

```py
# string concatenation
text = str(file) + ".txt"

# f-strings
text = f"{file}.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `text` is not what you expect. You currently create a tuple that could look like this: `(2, ".txt")`. If you want a string like `"2.txt"`, you need to concatenate the two parts:

```py
text = str(file) + ".txt"
```

Comment: This will fail with the following type error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: damn, you're right. fixed it, thanks!